# Is there any way to tell NSCollectionView that it can use memory more liberally?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview

I have a [`NSCollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionview) which creates items with its [`makeItem(withIdentifier:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionview/1528240-makeitem) function.

Performance is great, as each item loads its image on a background thread. This completes in about a tenth of a second, which means while I scroll there are blank spaces where I scrolled to for a moment. I think that's acceptable the very first time, but subsequent scrolling, I think, should just show the old items instead of recycling hidden ones.

**Is there any way I can tell `NSCollectionView` to more-aggressively cache, and keep views in memory longer?**

Comment: Can't you cache the items and images in your datasource?

Comment: @Willeke That's a workaround, certainly. Though, it seems like this is a reasonable behavior for a collection view to have.